# Why isn't this table being sorted correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Don't know why the table isn't being sorted into rows and columns correctly.
I am attempting to create a two dimensional array, and then use nested for loops to automatically create a table.

```js
list = [
  [12, 4, 22],
  [11, 32, 7],
  [9, 16, 13]
];
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  tablebody.innerHTML += "<tr>";
  for (var j = 0; j < list[i].length; j++) {
    tablebody.innerHTML += "<td>" + list[i][j] + "</td>";
  }
  tablebody.innerHTML += "</tr>"
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <thead id="tablehead">
    <tr>List[0]</tr>
    <tr>List[1]</tr>
    <tr>List[2]</tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tablebody">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you expand upon what you mean by "correctly"?

Comment: a few error, thead without tds but 3 tr . Also, you better use `document.createElement()`: https://jsfiddle.net/8wchnxr7/  ... https://jsfiddle.net/8wchnxr7/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add *fragements* to `innerHTML`.  When you do `tablebody.innerHTML+="<tr>";`, the browser automatically adds a closing `</tr>` right after.

You need to build the string into its own variable, then do `tablebody.innerHTML = yourTableVar;` afterwards.

```
var tableData = '';

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  tableData += "<tr>";
  for (var j = 0; j < list[i].length; j++) {
    tableData += "<td>" + list[i][j] + "</td>";
  }
  tableData += "</tr>"
}

tablebody.innerHTML = tableData;
```

Also, your HTML for for your `<thead>` is incorrect.  You need to have a `<tr>` as your header row and `<th>` tags with your column headers:

```
<thead id="tablehead">
    <tr>
        <th>List[0]</th>
        <th>List[1]</th>
        <th>List[2]</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const tablebody = document.querySelector('table#table tbody')
  ,   list =
       [ [ 12,  4, 22 ]
       , [ 11, 32,  7 ]
       , [  9, 16, 13 ]
       ]
for (let row of list) 
  {
  let nRow = tablebody.insertRow()
  for( let vCol of row)
    {
    nRow.insertCell().textContent = vCol
    }
  }
```

```css
body {
  background-color : black;
  color            : white;
  }
table  {
  border-collapse  : collapse;
  }
table td {
  padding    : 5px;
  width      : 20px;
  height     : 20px;
  border     : 1px solid green;
  text-align : center;
  }
table thead {
  background-color : darkblue;
  }
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>List[0]</td>
      <td>List[1]</td>
      <td>List[2]</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```